# z-song, админка laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Есть миграция с полем unigue pkey id, дело в том что она должна заполняться своеобразно и с админки, incrementing = false прописал, но даже в этом случае не отображает поле id для заполнения. дело поменялось когда я поменял нэйм поля на idVirtual.

```
protected function form()
    {
        $city_model = config('admin.database.cities_model');

        $form = new Form(new $city_model());

        $form->text('idVirtual', trans('admin.id'));
        $form->text('name', trans('admin.name_c'));
        $form->text('code', trans('admin.code'));
        $form->text('status', trans('admin.status'));
        $form->setAction('/admin/cities/new');

        return $form;
    }


    public function newCity(Request $r) {
        $arr = $_POST;
        foreach ($arr as $k => $v ){
            echo "</br>$k : $v</br>";
        }
    }
```

теперь я получил массив значении, но каким образом эти значения записать в бд?
Помогите пожалуйста я просто новичок.

Answer (score 1):

Решил вопрос следующим решением.

```
public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        self::creating(function ($model) {
            $model->id=$model->idVirtual;
            unset($model->idVirtual);
        });
    }
```

и в модель добавил:

```
public $primaryKey = 'id';
```